# Angular append directive template to table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have situation when i need to repeat multiple tbody in one table, what im trying to do is to make every tbody directive and i want its template to append to table, but when im put the directive inside the table tag its put his content outside the table.

the cart draw directive:

```
return {
    restrict   : 'AE',
    templateUrl: 'client/cart/views/cart-draw.html',
    scope      : {},
    replace: true,
    controller : controller
  }
```

the tpl:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="draw in CartService.items.draws track by $index">

  <tr>
    <td>
      //some content
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

the html:

```
<table class="table">

  <cart-draw></cart-draw>

</table>
```

here is the plunker, if you inspect element you will see the tbody is out of the table:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9wEGFE5K0w0ayp6qo8Lx?p=preview

Comment: You dont understand my question

Comment: A JS fiddle will help!

Comment: You got it :) updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because the `<table>` tag doesn't recognize your custom `<cart-draw>` element as a valid child.

I would modify like so: http://plnkr.co/edit/u88N76h5dvLAvR3C1kRs?p=preview

**index.html**

```
<table><tbody cart-draw></tbody></table>
```

**cart-draw.html**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="body in bodies">
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{body}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.bodies = ["hello1", "hello2", "hello3"];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a long pending issue in Angular's Github repo.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

I also stumbled upon to this problem once (with SVG). It happens because before rendering the directive, the template is cross verified with **HTML DTD** and  alone doesn't make sense (without  tag) and so it doesn't work. Same applies to `<tr>` and `<li>`

There are many solutions which uses `ng-transclude` and `link` functions to wrap it in respective parent tag and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a known & strange issue when it comes to directives & `<table>`'s.

I believe it actually comes in as `invalid` HTML at first, causing it somehow appear outside of your `<table>` tag.

Try making cart-draw an *attribute* of a `<tbody>`:

```
<table>
  <tbody cart-draw></tbody>
</table>
```

**[plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ns7LjBfuSLK81wUTCEWu?p=preview)**

This will make it work as intended.